# How I can give a view to my models.py in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**My models.py File**

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_time=models.DateTimeField( auto_now=True)
```

**Can You tell me how I can put this in my views.py and HTML file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to access the data from your models and pass it on to a template. In order to do this,

in views.py

```
from .models import Post
def your_view_function(request):
    data = Post.objects.all()
    context = { "data" : data, }
    return render(request, "<link_to_your_template>", context)
```

in your template,

```
{% for item in data %}
   <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
   <h1>{{ item.content }}</h1>
   {% endfor %}
```